# Dependency on a value (not a reference)

Tags: r, shiny

What is the best way to declare a dependency on a *value* rather than another variable.  The idea here is that if the value does not change it should not trigger further recomputations.  For example:

```
# In the code below we are displaying the result of an input divided by
# ten using integer division.  As a result, many different values result in
# the same value to be displayed and should not trigger re-rendering (ideally)
# However, the obvious implementation using reactive(...) does re-render.
# reactiveValues(...) seems to provide a solution.

library(shiny)

out <- function(...) cat(file = stderr(), ..., "\n")

server <- function(input, output) {

  vals <- reactiveValues()

  tenth <- function() {
    result <- input$n %/% 10
    out('Computing tenth:', input$n, '->', result)
    result
  }

  observeEvent(input$n, { 
    result <- tenth()
    out("Updating vals$tenth:", input$n, '->', result)
    vals$tenth <- result
  })

  output$tenth.val <- renderText({
    result <- vals$tenth
    out("Rendering tenth.val:", result)
    result
  })

  tenth.reactive <- reactive({
    result <- tenth()
    out("Executing tenth.reactive", result)
    result
  })

  output$tenth.ref <- renderText({
    result <- tenth.reactive()
    out("Rendering tenth.ref:", result)
    result
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("n", NULL, min = 0, max = 20, value = 3),
  'One tenth of the above value is',
  tags$ul(
    tags$li(textOutput('tenth.val', inline = T), '(val)'),
    tags$li(textOutput('tenth.ref', inline = T), '(ref)')
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As one slides from from 9 to 10 the stderr output is:

```
Computing tenth: 9 -> 0 
Updating vals$tenth: 9 -> 0 
Computing tenth: 9 -> 0 
Executing tenth.reactive 0 
Rendering tenth.ref: 0 
Computing tenth: 10 -> 1 
Updating vals$tenth: 10 -> 1 
Computing tenth: 10 -> 1 
Executing tenth.reactive 1 
Rendering tenth.ref: 1 
Rendering tenth.val: 1
```

Note that `Rendering tenth.val` only appears once.  I.e., the approach that uses *reactive values* avoids re-rendering when the output value does not change.  However `Rendering tenth.ref` appears twice since the cascade of invalidations does not notice that value did not change.

Is using `reativeValues()` the best way to achieve this effect?  (To me it seems a little round-about.)

Comment: Basically, yes :)

Comment: @JDL, thanks.  Is this discussed anywhere?  (I'm still new to Shiny, so it's hard to tell if anything I do is idiomatic Shiny or some aweful perversion which only technicall works.)

Comment: I've honestly no idea, I learned most of this by trial-and-error. I'd be interested to see if anyone posts any good links I'm not already aware of.